# Mootools 1.3.2 Request.HTML fetch table rows

Tags: cakephp, mootools

First off please don't bash me for using old technology (polling) and an old version of Mootools (1.3.2) as I don't have control over these factors.

Ok here's my problem.

I have a page which refreshes every few seconds to fetch new data from the database via AJAX. Ideally the structure of the returned value should be as such:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
```

After receiving this table row structure result, I need to append that to the current table in the page which essentially just adds a new record on the table if there are new records. If there's none, then no changes to the table are made.

Currently I am using

```
var req = new Request.HTML({url: url_to_get_new_rows, 
    onSuccess: function(html, responseHTML) {
        // append table row 'html' here
    }
}).send();
```

However, the returned value in the 'html' variable that I'm supposed to append at the end of the table only returns

```
1 2 3 4
```

This obviously is an undesired behavior as I need the `tr` and `td` elements to make it work.

I hope someone could help me with this problem.

**THANKS!**

Comment: The success funcion gives you `responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript` as arguments. You need to use the second argument. Is that online so we can have a look at what the server returns? otherwise just loop the second argument's elements and insert into the table. Docs: http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Request/Request.HTML

Comment: Sadly I'm working on my local host but the URL requested only returns a tr with a bunch of td's inside. Also, the docs you provided is for Mootools 1.5.1, I'm using 1.3.2 if that is important.

Comment: You can see the 1.3.2 docs here also: http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.3.2/Request/Request.HTML Something like this should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/earg8xvw/. Could you add more code of how you are using the results from the Request?

Comment: @Sergio here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asp_patrickgregorio/rtr271ga/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript:

```
new Request.HTML({
    url:'tr.php',
    onSuccess: function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript) {
        var tbody = document.id('tbody');

        tbody.set('html', tbody.get('html') + responseHTML);
        // or
        var tr = new Element('table', {'html': responseHTML}).getElement('tr');
        tr.inject(tbody);
    }
}).get();
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and I get the desired response when I log the responseHTML into the console. Instead of `1 2 3 4` I get `<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>` which is what I expect. But the `tbody.set('html', tbody.get('html') + responseHTML);` part doesn't work. I don't see the responseHTML being appended to the end of the table. Also, when I tried `var tr = new Element('table', {'html': responseHTML}).getElement('tr');` `tr.inject(tbody);`, I get error messages at the console saying _Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null_ which points to mootools.js line 3437.

Comment: var tbody = document.id('tbody'); 
have you got a tbody element with id="tbody" in yout pre-existing html 
resp. adapted your html/js?

Comment: here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asp_patrickgregorio/rtr271ga/) so that you have an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. It doesn't work but that is my current set-up.

Comment: @asp.patrickg you where missing a `#` in your ID selector: https://jsfiddle.net/rtr271ga/1/

Comment: @Sergio Oh wow, thanks. I am aware that in jQuery we use # to select by id. On Mootools however, after reading a couple bit, I've seen people select by id without the # and thought that this was the general way (Mootools way) and so I adopted this convention. Thanks this solved my problem!